# How to open just a single jquery dialog within a PHP while loop

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop, row

I have a HTML table, where rows are shown within a `while` loop.
In each row I have a `<td>`, and within each of those I place a `<img>`.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th class="text-left highlight">presso</th>
 </tr>
<?php
while...
?>
<div class="myClass" title="info" style="display: none;">
bla bla bla
</div>
 <tr>
  <td class="text-left">
   <img src="img/i.png" class="myImg" /><?php echo $while_loop_result;?>
  </td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Please notice the class **myClass** for the div and **myImg** for the img.

Now, I want to click on the `<img>` in each table row, and open a jquery dialog which corresponds to that specific row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.myClass').dialog(
{
      autoOpen: false,
      maxWidth:300,
      maxHeight: 300,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      modal: true,
      show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1200
      },
      hide: {
      effect: "drop",
      duration: 1200
      }
    }
);
$('.myClass').dialog('close');
$(".myImg").click(
 function (e) {
   $('.myClass').dialog('open');
 });
})
</script>
```

The script above opens **all** the dialog windows. If the table has five rows, by clicking on any of the five images, all the five dialog popups open.

How can I open **just the one I clicked on**?

Comment: `$('.myClass').click(function(){
$('.'+this)..dialog(
{
}`. You forgot to add click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its obvious if you refer to a class you all the classes will be opened. You need to assign separate ids to every element. The workaround for this should be similar to this.

```
     $sql = "Your query string";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
$i=1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
echo '<div class="myClass" id="expand-'.$i.'" title="info" style="display: none;">
bla bla bla
</div>
 <tr>
  <td class="text-left">
   <img src="img/i.png" class="myImg" id="'.$i.'"/>'.$row["somedatabasefield"].'
  </td>
 </tr>';
$i=$i+1;
}

}
```

Now when you have generated all the tds and divs we will see the jquery code accordingly. It should something like this. I haven't checked this on my own but this will give an idea what to do exactly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.myClass').dialog(
{
      autoOpen: false,
      maxWidth:300,
      maxHeight: 300,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      modal: true,
      show: {
      effect: "blind",
      duration: 1200
      },
      hide: {
      effect: "drop",
      duration: 1200
      }
    }
);
$('.myClass').dialog('close');
$(".myImg").click(
 function (e) {
   $('#expand-'+this.id).dialog('open');
 });
})
</script>
```

As you can see only one change in jquery is needed in this workaround.

Comment: Nice workaround. I was thinking about doing something using `each`, but your solution is much more straightforward.

Comment: Well thanx. I am glad it was helpful to you.